# Exporting A3 email from Outlook to PDF

Tags: vba, pdf, outlook

I have a VBA script that exports certain incoming emails to PDF via Word:

```
'Create a Word object
Dim wrdApp As Word.Application
Dim wrdDoc As Word.Document
Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open(FileName:=tmpFileName, Visible:=True)

Dim WshShell As Object
Dim SpecialPath As String
Dim strToSaveAs As String
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  MyDocs = "\\MY PATH TO FILES\"
strToSaveAs = MyDocs & "\" & sName & ".pdf"
wrdApp.ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:= _
strToSaveAs, ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, _
OpenAfterExport:=False, OptimizeFor:=wdExportOptimizeForPrint, _
Range:=wdExportCurrentPage, Item:= _
wdExportDocumentContent, IncludeDocProps:=True, KeepIRM:=True, _
CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, DocStructureTags:=True, _
BitmapMissingFonts:=True, UseISO19005_1:=False
```

It all works fine, but I've noticed that sometimes emails are trimmed on the right side - after investigation I've found that they are simply too wide for A4 page - they are in fact A3!

Unfortunately I can't see page size anywhere within the [Document.ExportAsFixedFormat Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb256835%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). Is there a way to either shrink the email to A4 or resize the PDF to A3?

Comment: You could self answer so searchers from the future know this has been answered. http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer  and then accept that answer http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
  wrdApp.ActiveDocument.PageSetup.PaperSize = WdPaperSize.wdPaperA3
```

resizes the print page to A3. Now I have to find a way to figure out how to determine the appropriate page size for emails (if doesn't fit into A4 use A3)